# Sed Match Number followed by string and return Number

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Hi i have a file containing the following:

```
   7    Y-N2
   8    Y-H
   9    Y-O2
```

I want to match it with the following sed command and get the number at the beginning of the line:

```
abc=$(sed -n -E "s/([0-9]*)(^[a-zA-Z])($j)/\1/g" file)
```

`$j` is a variable and contains exactly `Y-O2` or `Y-H`.

The Number is not the linenumber.

The Number is always followed by a Letter.

Before the Number are Whitespaces.

echoing `$abc` returns a whiteline.

Thanks

Comment: Why use sed for this? With awk you could simply do `awk -vk="$var" '$2==k{print $1}' file`

Comment: Expected Output is the Number saved in abc.

Comment: @user000001 can you explain "-vk" and the "k" before the print?

Comment: @Thunfisch: Sure, I 'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed seems to be overly complex for this task, but with awk you can write:

```
awk -vk="$var" '$2==k{print $1}' file
```

With `-vk="$var"` we set the `awk` variable `k` to the value of the `$var` shell variable.

Then, we use the `'filter{command}'` syntax, where the filter `$2==k` is that the second field is equal to the variable `k`. If we have a match, we print the first field with `{print $1}`.

Answer (score 3):

many problems here:

- there are spaces, you don't account for them
- the `^` must be *inside* the char class to make a negative letter
- you're using `-n` option, so you must use `p` command or nothing will ever be printed (and the `g` option is useless here)

working command (I have changed `-E` by `-n` because it was unsupported by my `sed` version, both should work):

```
sed -nr "s/ *([0-9]+) +([^a-zA-Z])($j)/\1/p" file
```

Note: `awk` seems more suited for the job. Ex:

```
awk -v j=$j '$2 == j { print $1 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
abc=$(sed -n "s/^ *\([0-9]*\) *Y-[OH]2*.*/\1/p" file)
```

**Explanations:**

- `^ *`: in lines starting with any number of spaces
- `\([0-9]*\)`: following number are captured using backreference
- `*`: after any number of spaces
- `Y-[OH]2*`: search for `Y-` string followed by `N` or `H` with optional `2`
- `\1/p`: captured string `\1` is output with `p` command